# VNC server connection refused (111) when trying to connect

Tags: ssl, vnc, vnc-server, stunnel, vnc-viewer

I am trying to incorporate SSL with my App so it use a secure connection when accessing through vnc viewers. Based on logs I don't think it even passes the handshaking stage.

Server Configuration:

```
pid = <location>/stunnel.pid  
cert = <location>/SystemCred.pem  

[websocket]  
accept = <hostname>:9999  
connect = 127.0.0.1:1111
```

I am using tightVNC with SSL.
    foreground = yes
    pid =
    client = yes
    debug = 6

```
options = ALL

cert = /home/tweet/Desktop/cert/SystemCred.pem

#[vnc_stunnel]
#accept = localhost:5930
connect = <server_ip>:9999
```

Copied the **SystemCred.pem** of server and specified it in the **MyCert** configuration of tightVNC.

**Client error logs:**

```
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG5[ui]: Reading configuration from file /tmp/ss_vncviewer23188.4043.MzSbol  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG5[ui]: UTF-8 byte order mark not detected  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG5[ui]: FIPS mode disabled  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG6[ui]: Initializing inetd mode configuration  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG6[ui]: Loading certificate from file: /home/tweet/Desktop/cert/SystemCred.pem  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG6[ui]: Certificate loaded from file: /home/tweet/Desktop/cert/SystemCred.pem  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG6[ui]: Loading private key from file: /home/tweet/Desktop/cert/SystemCred.pem  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG4[ui]: Insecure file permissions on /home/tweet/Desktop/cert/SystemCred.pem  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG6[ui]: Private key loaded from file: /home/tweet/Desktop/cert/SystemCred.pem  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG4[ui]: Service [stunnel] needs authentication to prevent MITM attacks  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG5[ui]: Configuration successful  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG5[ui]: Service [stunnel] accepted connection  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG6[ui]: s_connect: connecting <server_ip>:9999  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG5[ui]: s_connect: connected <server_ip>:9999  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG5[ui]: Service [stunnel] connected remote server from 10.194.6.207:46832  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG6[ui]: SNI: sending servername: <server_ip>  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG6[ui]: Certificate verification disabled  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG6[ui]: Certificate verification disabled  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG6[ui]: SSL connected: new session negotiated  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG6[ui]: Negotiated TLSv1.2 ciphersuite ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256-bit encryption)  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG3[ui]: SSL_read: Connection reset by peer (104)  
2016.10.04 17:22:01 LOG5[ui]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to SSL, 0 byte(s) sent to socket  
vncviewer: VNC server closed connection
```

**Server error logs:**
Service [websocket] accepted connection from :46830
s_connect: connect 127.0.0.1:1111: Connection refused (111)

I'm really stuck and I don't know what is happening. I'm failry new with this one. Hope you guys can help.

Comment: "connection refused" sounds like there is nothing listening on 127.0.0.1:1111, what did you think should be there? What would `netstat -an|grep LISTEN|grep 1111` show?

Comment: Hi stefan, got these results: tcp        0      0 :::1111                 :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: that sounds like an IPv6 listen, you are trying to talk IPv4 ?

Comment: what do you mean? how do I check that? sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: oh. in my socket settings i added BindToDevice=eth0 and did not specify ipv6

Comment: I have no experience with IPv6 and if that would turn out to be the issue, then you probably should post a new question about stunnel/ipv6.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the 'SSH method'.

I faced similar issue, of which the error exactly was `Connection refused (111)`.

Not wanted to reboot.

However, I tried with that 'secure' method (For my instance, just follow the archlinux wiki page ~), and worked...

---

Note that another strange point is that

- originally when I run `vncserver` with my primary user in that server-pc, everything seems fine, except the KDE seems not support desktop screens simultaneously on both server and client ...
- so I tried again with the new fresh user, like said above, and stucked ...